# How to get categories with products count through brand in laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel

My Product Model belongs To category and brand. I want get products count in categories by using brand. How do I form a relationships in laravel 5

Comment: Share your relationship code so that we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use DB::raw

```
$brand
    ->products()
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count, category_id'))
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response but I have only brand ID I want to get categories with products count products belongs to brand

Comment: @katamrajender You have to explain it a little bit more. You want to get all products for brand and then group it by category and count?

Comment: Yes that's what I want